# wait for single object function usage

Tags: c++, waitforsingleobject

I am using `WaitForSingleObject()` function for implementing wait in my program.

```
WaitForSingleObject(eventToBeSigaled, timeOut);
```

all of us know that this function wait for the event to be signaled for the specified amount of time.

But I want to know that what happens when the event has already singled before entering to this call, at that time is the wait will `fail(WAIT_FAILED)`? Please answer this with proper reason. I want to know this little deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your first question: if the event is already signaled, your `Wait()` would return immediately returning `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.

Second question: One of the circumstances `WAIT_FAILED` is returned is if the event handle is closed when `Wait()` is called. In this case, the OS scheduler won't be able to process the `Wait()` call and hence returns `WAIT_FAILED`.

Note that at the end of the day, the `Wait()` functions are a means for the user threads to pass the CPU back to the OS until a certain condition is met. Depending on your needs, you use one of the OS primitives as a condition (semaphore, mutex, events, etc). The OS scheduler in turn checks this condition to determine if your worker thread should be given CPU time slice thereby ensuring that all threads (and hence all processes) get a fair share of the system resources.

Answer (score 0):

you should check it's documentation first, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`Remarks`

`The WaitForSingleObject function checks the current state of the specified object. If the object's state is nonsignaled, the calling thread enters the wait state until the object is signaled or the time-out interval elapses.`